# Linux get pid of program launched via script with execl

Tags: c++, linux, shell, pid

I have a piece of code that launches another program as child process.

```
pid = execlp("path-to/program", "path-to/program", nullptr);
```

This returns me the pid of the process i launched so I can access it. Now we need to launch a process via a shell script. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path-to/program
/path-to/program
#or:
wine /path-to/program.exe
```

C++:

```
pid = execlp("/path-to/shelscript.sh", "/path-to/shellscript.sh", nullptr);
```

When I now call execl it will return the pid of the shell, not of the launched process. I could check if the the path to the program contains ".sh" and increment the pid by one, but this will not always work. Is there a cleaner & more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Do you have control over the launched scripts (can you change their code)?

Comment: Yes, that's possible

Comment: You could think about a file/pipe based communication then. But so far I can see that everything executes in order, what do you need the pids for?

Comment: I have to access the process with process_vm_writev / process_vm_readv

Comment: `execlp` doesn't return (unless there is an error) it replaces the process. You probably need `fork`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but you could try using `exec` in the shell script, which would replace the shell process with the program it starts. Also, what Galik said.

Comment: The exec command was exactly what I was looking for! Could you post an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 0):

If you start a process in a shell script, the variable `$!` contains the pid of the process just created.  You could e.g. output this using echo and start the shell script using `popen()` and read the pid from there.